# Spring Environment: order of systemProperties and systemEnvironment

Tags: spring, spring-environment

Is it possible to control order of resolution from Spring Environment from underlying PropertySources?

For example.

I have OS environment variable

```
ENV key=os
```

and run java with System environment variable

```
java -Dkey=system
```

What the output of Invoking method m on bean of class A?
How to change order of scanning SystemEnvironmentPropertySource  or MapPropertySource [name='systemProperties']?

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Component
class A{
    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    public void m(){
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("key"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this documentation help you? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @getjackx, no, I was asking about vanilla Spring Core

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, sorry for inconvenience:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html

> ```` In addition to the usual functions of a ConfigurableEnvironment
>   such as property resolution and profile-related operations, this
>   implementation configures two default property sources, to be searched
>   in the following order:
>
> ```
> system properties
> system environment variables
> ```
>
> That is, if the key "xyz" is present both in the JVM system properties
>   as well as in the set of environment variables for the current
>   process, the value of key "xyz" from system properties will return
>   from a call to environment.getProperty("xyz"). This ordering is chosen
>   by default because system properties are per-JVM, while environment
>   variables may be the same across many JVMs on a given system. Giving
>   system properties precedence allows for overriding of environment
>   variables on a per-JVM basis.
>
> These default property sources may be removed, reordered, or replaced;
>   and additional property sources may be added using the
>   MutablePropertySources instance available from
>   AbstractEnvironment.getPropertySources(). See ConfigurableEnvironment
>   Javadoc for usage examples.  ````